# Motherboard doesn't see bootable Linux USB

Tags: linux, boot, usb, motherboard

As the title says. I have a bootable Ubuntu 18.04 USB, I try to to install Linux but the only message it gives out is: "Reboot and select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media for selected boot device and press a key".
When I go to the bios settings it clearly says that it sees the USB itself however when trying to boot through it in the boot menu it returns the same message as earlier.

**Things I tried**
Changing the boot order (USB drive first)
Testing the USB on 2 different computers (It works on them)
Changing the CSM settings (Tested all the UEFI and Legacy settings)
Tried putting in a Vista bootable USB (same message)
Tried a different USB
Restored the motherboard to default settings
Scooped out an old hard drive from an old server I know for a fact runs Windows Server 2003 (motherboard doesn't see the hard drive)

I am out of ideas, so I write here as a last resort if nobody will help me it's going to the trash.

**Specs**
Intel Pentium G3220
8GB Ram
MSI MS-7848 motherboard
Intel 160 GB SSD

**Backstory**
I was running Windows 7 happily but then the end of support came so I was forced to upgrade to Windows 10. As expected the computer was freezing after like max. 2 minutes of use.
After trying everything online to stop the freezing, in a last ditch attempt I changed the active partition in the settings, after the restart   I arrived at the message described up. So I decided to install Linux.

Comment: How about disabling secure boot in your BIOS. Have you done that? Also, what did you use to build your bootable USB?

Comment: @KingDuken Yes I tried disabling secure boot. Regarding the USB's I first used my Mac's terminal and used some commands to make it (followed a youtube tutorial), then I used software called unetbootin. When it comes to the vista USB I think I used Rufus. But I don't see why it would matter since it works on my 2 other pc's.

Comment: You have a lot of information in your post, but much of it is not relevent. Interesting are: 1) How is your firmware configured (UEFI normal boots, EUFI with backward compatability, is secure boot on (KingDuken already mentioned that, but repeating.  2) How did you create the iso. With tons of details. E.g. it might only work in BIOS and not proper EFI).   3> How the the computer where it boots on configured. E.g. if that is an cient desktop with BIOS firmware and it boots then we already know your pendrive is configured for BIOS boot, not ESP boot.

Comment: Hmm 50 sec difference betwen my writing it and your answer to Duke.  Can you add the precise settings used in rufus?

Comment: @Hennes 1. TBH I don't know how my firmware is configured. I tried whatever an online tutorial told me to do (which is to change the CSM settings <<I tried setting everything to UEFI mode, then to UEFI and Legacy and then to just Legacy>>). As I said in the main post I turned off secure boot on and off to no avail. 2) I completely forgot the settings for the vista bootable drive (I made it years ago) while in the unetbootin I din't change any settings I just selected the distribution and hit run. 3) I don't really know and I don't know how to check.

Comment: So I think something is wrong with your USB. You mentioned that this is an old computer and it worked on two other computers. I'm suspecting that your USB flash drive could be USB3.0 and your computer obviously won't be able to take that. I looked up images of this motherboard you mentioned and I didn't see any indication of any USB3.0 slots (except near the the PCIe slots). Sure it's capable of being detected by your BIOS but as far as reading from it, I highly doubt it will work.

Comment: @KingDuken It would make sense but the first USB I used is a 2.0 drive and I highly doubt that a motherboard from 2013 would still have USB 1.0

Comment: In situations like this you should try a bootable usb that  already booted on another computer... In situations like this you should try a bootable usb that has already been booted on another computer. It rarely happens that you have not checked the "make bootable" box and even if you use the linux image created specifically for the usb stick, and you have a usb stick with the whole system inside... well the pen cannot boot because it is not actually _bootable_.